# Java General projects managment?

Tags: java, javafx

Hello I work with java and netBeans IDE, I have some projects on one computer and other projects on another computer.
The problem is that when I am at home, I need access to projects from the work computer and vise-versa. How to have all projects no matter where I am (work on work pc or home on the home pc)?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
**work pc:**
project 1
project 2
**Home pc:** 
project 3
project 4
**work&&home.. different pc .. etc**
project 1
project 2
project 3
project 4
```

Comment: You need to be using version control.

Comment: You can use GIT for it. https://github.com/

Comment: ok but i want them private ? git is paid for private ?other option

Comment: Well you can go with primitive style of making cloud account ;D and use cloud folder , use it as project loc - simple,free.Bud you use it for work , so why not pay for github account?

Comment: i am new to  java and just want to learn it , im not sure if i am going to use.that's why i think thats its to early to pay for something that i might not need

Comment: Then as i sayd, go with cloud folder.Its just too easy, open dropbox account.At least you wont have to watch any tutorial for setting up git.

Comment: What about the most simple solution to put them on a portable disk or USB stick?

Comment: @mipa and who wants to carry that around ?;D common.Just a fact you have to plug it in every time is pain ;D